# Servo Motor Control using IOIO board

Tags: java, android, ioio

How to control Servo Motor with Android using IOIO board? What is the android code behind it and what kind of input is required?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the question? Have you tried anything so far? What is your actual problem?

Comment: The question is badly put but this post has a good answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common question when using the IOIO, and the answer is easily Googleable. Also, please adhere to the SO guidelines when posting, showing what you have tried, and what you are having problems with.

Servo control is PWM, which is a function built into the IOIO library:

```
PwmOutput pwm = ioio.openPwmOutput(pinNum, freq);
pwm.setDutyCycle(dc);
pwm.setPulseWidth(pw);
```

[See this page](https://github.com/ytai/ioio/wiki/PWM-Output)